Build CI CD pipeline Airflow spark
Using GCP Dataproc and Airflow composer, able to deploy the pyspark script and success the result. After this, I'm not aware of artifact preparation and Building CI CD pipeline, Which tool should i use. How to build a standard one.
Other ETL tools like Talend, The application itself build the artifact and we can control the version. Since Pyspark and airflow are script based stuff how can we achieve the artifact preparation and CICD operation

You can use Cloud Build to build your application.
